# Javascript works locally but not on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a problem with some JavaScript code. It works fine when I test the website locally but doesn't work on the server unless I reload the page. The code is below. Please let me know if you need more details.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#header_inbox_bar" ).click(function() {

const inboxtopcount = $('#inboxtopcount')
const badgedanger = inboxtopcount.parent('.badge-danger')

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'controllers/ctrl_client_update_inbox_notifications.php',
  success (res) {
    if (res) {

      badgedanger.hide()
      inboxtopcount.hide()
    } 
  },

});
});
});
```

Comment: Same origin policy?

Comment: are you seeing any errors?

Comment: please show us the error

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+C .. .let's know the console out .  (or Shift+Cmd+C if you are MAC user)

Comment: I don't see any error in the console, it works fine in localhost but not on the server.

Comment: Could you give us the URL of your script running on the server, so we could investigate?

Comment: Hi, yes you can, this si the url www.karibusana.altervista.org and you can login with prova/prova or prova2/prova2 if you try to send a message from this url http://karibusana.altervista.org/clients/client_inbox_compose.php for example prova sends a message to prova2 then you should see e notification on the topbar and when you click on the notification should disappear and show a dropdown menu. Please bear in mind it is under development and i've just started to study php and javascript. Thanks for your help

Comment: on page load - SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - so, no errors in the console is not true from the start

Comment: `Deprecation warning: moment().subtract(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().subtract(number, period).` on the www page

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX do you think this can cause the problem? The syntax error is related to index.php which is in the comment and the second error is inside a file which i'm not using. It still doesn't explain why it works in local machine but not on the server i think.

Comment: not sure, I just see that you said there are "no errors" - but I see an error and a warning - who knows if it's the problem - no idea what code is issuing the errors

Comment: the `$.ajax` is executing ... receives nothing in response - so the client side seems to be fine, it's doing exactly what it should with no response ... nothing - seems the issue is server side

Comment: I've tried it in two different servers and still the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is your DOM elements are not binding to the jQuery in time. Also, try inspecting your jQuery for syntax errors or any missing syntax.

To address any binding issues on load, try using the jQuery 'on' method so you can then pass it your #header_inbox_bar element and have it bind at a later time. like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('click', '#header_inbox_bar', function() {

        const inboxtopcount = $('#inboxtopcount');
        const badgedanger = inboxtopcount.parent();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'controllers/ctrl_client_update_inbox_notifications.php',
            success(res) {
                badgedanger.hide();
            },
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Wow this is working fine :) many thanks Andres. I've got so much to learn :)